# Maximum distance between mid-point of chord of ellipse

Tags: trigonometry, conic-sections

Let $E$ be the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{16}+\frac{y^2}{9}=1$. For any three distinct points $P,Q$ and $Q′$ on $E$, let $M(P, Q)$ be the mid-point of the line segment joining $P$ and $Q$, and $M(P, Q′)$ be the mid-point of the line segment joining $P$ and $Q′$. Then the maximum possible value of the distance between $M(P,Q)$ and $M(P,Q′)$, as $P,Q$ and $Q ′$ vary on $E$, is ___ .

My approach is as follow

Let $P(4cos\alpha,3sin\alpha)$,$Q(4cos\theta_1,3sin\theta_1)$,$Q′(4cos\theta_2,3sin\theta_2)$

$M(P, Q)=(\frac{4(cos\theta_1+cos\theta_2)}{2},)$

Let the mid point be represented as $M\left( {P,Q} \right) = \left( {\frac{{4\left( {\cos \alpha  + \cos {\theta _1}} \right)}}{2},\frac{{3\left( {\sin \alpha  + \sin {\theta _1}} \right)}}{2}} \right);M\left( {P,Q'} \right) = \left( {\frac{{4\left( {\cos \alpha  + \cos {\theta _2}} \right)}}{2},\frac{{3\left( {\sin \alpha  + \sin {\theta _2}} \right)}}{2}} \right)$

$\frac{1}{4}\sqrt {{{\left( {4\cos \alpha  + 4\cos {\theta _1} - \left( {4\cos \alpha  + 4\cos {\theta _2}} \right)} \right)}^2} + {{\left( {3\sin \alpha  + 3\sin {\theta _1} - \left( {3\sin \alpha  + 3\sin {\theta _2}} \right)} \right)}^2}} $

$\frac{1}{4}\sqrt {16\left( {{{\cos }^2}{\theta _1} + {{\cos }^2}{\theta _2} - 2\cos {\theta _1}\cos {\theta _2}} \right) + 9\left( {{{\sin }^2}{\theta _1} + {{\sin }^2}{\theta _2} - 2\sin {\theta _1}\sin {\theta _2}} \right)} $

$\frac{1}{4}\sqrt {16{{\cos }^2}{\theta _1} + 9{{\sin }^2}{\theta _1} + 16{{\cos }^2}{\theta _2} + 9{{\sin }^2}{\theta _2} - 32\cos {\theta _1}\cos {\theta _2} - 18\sin {\theta _1}\sin {\theta _2}} $

$\frac{1}{4}\sqrt {18 + 7\left( {{{\cos }^2}{\theta _1} + {{\cos }^2}{\theta _2}} \right) - 14\cos {\theta _1}\cos {\theta _2} - 18\left( {\cos \left( {{\theta _1} - {\theta _2}} \right)} \right)} $

${\cos ^2}{\theta _1} = \frac{{1 + \cos 2{\theta _1}}}{2};{\cos ^2}{\theta _2} = \frac{{1 + \cos 2{\theta _2}}}{2}$

${\cos ^2}{\theta _1} + {\cos ^2}{\theta _2} = 1 + \frac{{2\cos \left( {{\theta _1} + {\theta _2}} \right)\cos \left( {{\theta _1} - {\theta _2}} \right)}}{2} = 1 + \cos \left( {{\theta _1} + {\theta _2}} \right)\cos \left( {{\theta _1} - {\theta _2}} \right)$

$\frac{1}{4}\sqrt {18 + 7\left( {1 + \cos \left( {{\theta _1} + {\theta _2}} \right)\cos \left( {{\theta _1} - {\theta _2}} \right)} \right) - 7\left( {\cos \left( {{\theta _1} + {\theta _2}} \right) + \cos \left( {{\theta _1} - {\theta _2}} \right)} \right) - 18\left( {\cos \left( {{\theta _1} - {\theta _2}} \right)} \right)} $

$\frac{1}{4}\sqrt {25 + 7\cos \left( {{\theta _1} + {\theta _2}} \right)\left( {\cos \left( {{\theta _1} - {\theta _2}} \right) - 1} \right) - 25\left( {\cos \left( {{\theta _1} - {\theta _2}} \right)} \right)} $

How do we proceed from here , we get the official answer **4** when $\theta_1=0$ & $\theta_2=\pi$

Comment: Inside square root you have, $18 + 7 (\cos\theta_1 - \cos\theta_2)^2 - 18 \cos (\theta_1 - \theta_2)$. Max of $ - 18 \cos (\theta_1 - \theta_2)$ is $18$ when $\cos (\theta_1 - \theta_2) = - 1$. Max of $|\cos\theta_1 - \cos\theta_2| $ is $2$. Both are reached when $\theta_1$ is $0$ and $\theta_2$ is $\pi$ or vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $X\equiv M(P,Q)$ and  $Y\equiv M(P,Q')$. Using the [midpoint theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) $(\triangle PXY\sim \triangle PQQ')$,
$$|XY|=\frac{1}{2}\cdot|QQ'|$$
$|QQ'|$ is maximum when $Q$ and $Q'$ lie on the major axis of the ellipse  $\dfrac{x^2}{16}+\dfrac{y^2}{9}$ (the two farthest points on an ellipse). Hence, $Q=(\pm 4,0)$ and $Q'=(\mp4,0)$.

Therefore,
$$\max(|XY|)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot8=\boxed{4}$$